# Django admin Login page giving error "incorrect username password" although I am using correct

Tags: python, django, django-models, authentication, admin

This is my model class

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import PermissionsMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import BaseUserManager

    class UserProfileManager(BaseUserManager):
        """Helps Djamgo work with our custom user model"""

        def create_user(self,email,name,password=None):

            if not email:
                raise ValueError('users must have an email address')
            #normalizing the email address convert it to the lowercase

            email = self.normalize_email(email)
            user = self.model(email=email, name=name)
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)



            return user

        def create_superuser(self,email,name,password):

            user = self.create_user(email,name,password)
            user.is_superuser =True
            user.is_staff = True

    class UserProfile(AbstractBaseUser,PermissionsMixin):
        email = models.EmailField(max_length=255,unique = True)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        related_name = "+"

        object = UserProfileManager()

        USERNAME_FIELD = "email"
        REQUIRED_FIELDS  = ['name']

        #helper funtionality

        def full_name(self):
            """Use to get full name of the user"""
            return self.name

        def short_name(self):
                """Use to get short name name of the user"""
                return self.name

        def __str__(self):
           `enter code here`return self.email
```

My `setting.py` contains everything
and my db is sync and I have already created a superuser. When I am trying to access my admin from admin login page it gives an error "please login with correct email password " But I have already ensured 5 times that I am using correct email password!

Comment: it seems you have missing elements https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example

Comment: you may find the problem if you check user record with some kind of [database viewer tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/database-tool-window.html)

Comment: I hav tried everything checked the urls as well . Not even my api views are getting connected to the urls